# jQuery $.ajax() var automatically $.abort()ed if reinitialized?

Tags: jquery, abort, automatic-properties

If a `var` is set to a jQuery `$.ajax()` call like so

```
var ajaxVar = $.ajax(...
```

will `ajaxVar`'s ajax request automatically be `$.abort()`ed if `ajaxVar` is reinitialized?

I have examined the docs, and I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't be aborted. There isn't even any requirement to assign the result of `$.ajax()` to a variable, many applications don't bother.

Comment: @Gracchus with rapid requests, it's probably better to instead throttle them rather than abort them. For example, with a search-as-you-type field, only perform the ajax if they stop performing keydown events for longer than 250ms.